# How to wait validate component when i call a function in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to implement my own validator component for inputs in React native, my component receives a type of function to validate, setFunction for set("return") the result and a property for to know if is enabled.

**Validator.tsx**

```
const OnlyNumbers=(value:any, message:string="Error number format")=>{
  let match=false;
  if(typeof value =="number")
    match=true;
  if(typeof value=="string")
    match= /^[0-9]*$/.test(value);

  return match ? '' : message;
}

const Email=(value:string, message:string="Error email format" ):string=>{
   let match=false;
   match= /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(value);
   return match ? '' : message;
}

const Validator=(props)=>{
  const {setResult, typeValidate, enable=true , defStyle={color:'red', fontSize:15}} = props;
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(enable){
        //to invoke received function validate
        let sms = typeValidate()
        setText(sms)
        //returns if exists an error
        setResult(sms.length>0)
    }   
  }, [enable, setResult])

  return(
    <>
    {enable && text.length>0 ? <Text style={defStyle}>{text}</Text>:null}
    </>
  );
}

export const ValidatorType={
 OnlyNumbers,
 Email,
}

export default Validator;
```

**Implementation.tsx**

```
import Validator, {ValidatorType} from '../Components/Validator'

const Implementation=(props)=>{
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [telephone, setTelephone] = useState('');
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [errorForm, setErrorForm] =useState(false);

  async function RegisterTaster(){
    setSubmit(true)
    if(!errorForm){
       //do something.....
    }
  }

  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Email..." defaultValue={email} onChangeText={txt=> setEmail(txt)} style={Styles.txtInputs} />
      <Validator typeValidate={()=>ValidatorType.Email(email)} setResult={resp=> setErrorForm(resp)} enable={submit} defStyle={Styles.txtInputsError} /> 
      <TextInput placeholder="Telephone..." defaultValue={telephone} onChangeText={txt=> setTelephone(txt)} style={Styles.txtInputs} />
      <Validator typeValidate={()=>ValidatorType.OnlyNumbers(telephone)} setResult={resp=> setErrorForm(resp)} defStyle={Styles.txtInputsError} /> 

      <Button primary style={Styles.btnRegister} onPress={async ()=> await RegisterTaster() }> 
                        <Text style={Styles.txtRegister}>Register</Text> 
      </Button>
    <View>
  )
}
```

Actually in **RegisterTaster()** first, i set the **submit to true** for **update the enable prop** in each validator; i want in that moment **if exists an error**, the **Validator update errorForm** before continue to the next if for to know if do or not something...

How can i wait until the validator updates the errorForm before evaluating the next  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define a value for set the result of the specify validation like (setIsValidEmail):

```
<Validator typeValidate={()=>ValidatorType.Email(email)} value={email} setResult={resp=> setIsValidEmail(resp)} visible={enabledValidator} />
```

And in the function i ask for the result:

```
 if(isValidEmail)
 {...do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use async and await

```
const Email=(value:string, message:string="Error email format" ):string=>{
   let match=false;
   match= /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(value);
   return match ? '' : message;
}

const Validator= async(props)=>{
  const {setResult, typeValidate, enable=true , defStyle={color:'red', fontSize:15}} = props;
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(enable){
        //to invoke received function validate
        let sms = typeValidate()
        setText(sms)
        //returns if exists an error
        setResult(sms.length>0)
    }   
  }, [enable, setResult])

  return(
    <>
    {enable && text.length>0 ? <Text style={defStyle}>{text}</Text>:null}
    </>
  );
}

export const ValidatorType={
 OnlyNumbers,
 Email,
}

export default Validator;
```

and use await everywhere you need

Comment: Await in setSubmit() ?